# Why don't we unite all countries?

Tags: political-theory

I get inspiration from the human body which is a very complex system. The human body does not divide itself into multiple parts which are controlled separately. I.e. there is not a separate nervous system only for a finger or an arm.

Now let's compare the human body to our planet. The planet is so small, in respect to the universe, that dividing it into multiple countries causes only more damage to it and it's inhabitants. The best model in my opinion is to "remove" all the countries and have a single united control for whole the planet.

This control system is then divided into multiple subsystems where each control a specific part. For example: natural resources system, economic system, animal health system, animal protection system, education system, infrastructure system and so on.

This, in my opinion is the only long term solution to our existence. So back to my question, what don't or can't we remove the countries? Is it because of our ego or are there disadvantages of such a system?

Comment: Individual cells within your body are somewhat autonomous.

Comment: If we're using the body analogy, my stomach and brain are often at war with each other. I'm pretty sure they'll never be united under a common regime.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea.  Not only should we unite all people under one flag we could put all the undesirable people into work camps, and weed out any one that are not genetically superior.  I wonder why no one has ever tried that before....

Comment: @Chad - they did. It was called Eugenics Wars... errr wrong Stack Exchange

Comment: So you're asking people to ["Imagine there's no countries"](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ulwAAOxyDLZSCTHk/s-l300.jpg)?

Comment: @Pharap that's like "imagine no possessions" being sung by a multi-millionaire.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The more theoretical answer is that, to live in a country, the people in that country have to agree to a set of governing principles (e.g. the American Constitution), and the political landscape of the entire world is too diverse to support a consensus necessary to create a single government. What do you do when some people want liberal democracy, others want secular authoritarianism, and yet others want Sharia law without any of these groups comprising a majority or even a substantial plurality?

The more practical answer is that people don't want to do this. For example, the recent European elections saw a large surge in [far right parties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Parliament_election,_2014) because those parties are Euroskeptic, i.e. they do not like the European Union, and Palestinians [don't want to live in the same country as Israelis](http://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Abbas-wants-not-a-single-Israeli-in-future-Palestinian-state-321470). Your political model needs to account for the existence and opinions of actual people.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that both examples are not necessarily majority opinions of the citizens. They tend to be minority opinions of the politicians. (So, it's not necessarily the opinions of actual people as much as the opinions of actual politicians.)